# Live connection to SSAS greyed out in Power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi

the live connection option when I connect to SSAS cube is greyed out in a specific pbix file:
https://s31.postimg.org/lernolvez/ssas_live_connection.jpg

However if I open a new file and start from scratch everything works perfectly and I can select the option.

Any ideas?

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Found, it is a limitation unfortunately..

Question: If I created a live connection, can I connect to another data source in the same Power BI Desktop file?

Answer: No. You cannot explore live data and connect to another type of data source in the same file. If you’ve already imported data or connected to a different data source in a Power BI Desktop file, you’ll need to create a new file to explore live.

Source: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-analysis-services-tabular-data/